# SQL LIKE for partial sentence value

Tags: sql, sql-like, phrase

I have a database (change) which I am trying to create an sql report on the detail field value. The issue is that the detail value displays a "phrase" and I need to evaluate based on this phrase, or a part of it.

SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM change
WHERE change.detail LIKE '%To: [Step Two]%'
```

I want it to display all of the values where detail contains "To: [1. Step Two]" but the result is consistently not returning anything, where there are table values for this. Following is an example of the full value of the detail field:
"[Step] Changed From: [1. Step One] To: [1. Step Two]"
The items in [] represent other values in the database as well

Comment: It works here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51981/5/0

Comment: So the issues is that the full value to evaluate is between the quotes in the following "[Step] Changed From: [1. Step One] To: [1. Step Two]" I need to only display results which have the later part of the phrase "To: [1. Step Two]" and leave the initial being a multi char wildcard as the part "[Step] Changed From: [1. Step One]" could be a multitude of things. I feel that the brackets in the resulting value cause an issue when including them in the LIKE statement as [1. Step Two] is actually what is in the statement and needs to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you're using SQL Server/TSQL, the problem you have is that [the square bracket characters have a special meaning:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

> [ ] Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set
>   ([abcdef]).
>
> WHERE au_lname LIKE '[C-P]arsen' finds author last names ending with
>   arsen and starting with any single character between C and P, for
>   example Carsen, Larsen, Karsen, and so on. In range searches, the
>   characters included in the range may vary depending on the sorting
>   rules of the collation.

In order to literally match the square bracket characters, you need to [escape them:](http://web.archive.org/web/20150519072547/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html)

```
LIKE '%To: \[Step Two\]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: Thank you this helped . . . my apologies for the poor explanation

Answer (score 2):

If this is Microsoft SQL Server then you can escape brackets:

```
SELECT *
FROM change
WHERE change.detail LIKE '%To: \[Step Two\]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Brackets used `LIKE` clause stand for a character range, So `[Step Two]` matches a character after `To:` that is either S,t,E,p, ,w, or o.

You can read about this on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is the square brackets introduce character constants.  Here is one solution:

```
where change.detail like '%To:  ___Step Two_%'
```

This just takes the risk that the square brackets are really needed for the match.

```
where change.detail like '%To:  __[[]Step Two]%'
```

An alternative is to escape those characters:

```
where change.detail like '%To:  __![Step Two!]%' escape '!'
```